# Spring Cloud Contract Setting `stubsMode` at runtime

Tags: configuration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

We're using Spring Cloud Contract for testing our services. I was wondering if there is some way to set the `stubsMode` at runtime, as opposed to being an option on the annotation:

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {...}, stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL)
```

If the annotation is the only way to set this option, we'll need to have two separate classes, one for local and one for remote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties. We describe it in the docs. Just pass the system prop stubrunner.stubs-mode=local or an env var STUBRUNNER_STUBS_MODE=LOCAL